# I am unable to to install any new software

Tags: software-installation

I want to install new software but whenever I open up the software center I get an error saying something needs to be repaired and that I can't install anything until it gets fixed.It gives me a option to repair but when I allow it nothing happens just an endless message saying " waiting for apt-get to exit". Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try reinstalling software-center. Open you terminal (Crtl+T or via Applications) then type the following two commands: 

`sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`

Comment: Please add the exact error message(s) in code blocks, so we can help you.

Comment: Have you restarted the system since?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always a case on a system that hasn't finished it's previous installation.

Configure any partially installed software.

```
sudo dpkg --configure --all
```

Install any required dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man apt-get` :

> **apt-get** is the command-line tool for handling packages, and may be
>          considered the user's "back-end" to other tools using the APT library.

---

> waiting for apt-get to exit

You may have another instance of `apt-get` running at the same time.

You can see what apt is doing by opening a terminal and typing `ps ax | grep apt`.

For example:

```
2683 ?        SNl    0:17 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
5603 pts/1    S+     0:00 sudo apt-get update
5604 pts/1    S+     0:00 apt-get update
5607 pts/1    S+     0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
```

The possible workaround is *wait for apt-get* to exit or *restart* your  system and make sure no other application run. No Update Manager , or terminal with `apt-get`.

Please **do not try to forcefully end apt**. If you want to do it forcefully, you can use `sudo killall apt-get` but **don't** do that.

Useful references [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/369203/439451) and [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+question/207896).